# Ionic 2 Promesa retorna __zone_symbol__value array

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

Estoy usando Ionic 2 y tengo un provider que es el encargado de hacer peticiones http a un servidor.

Uso el siguiente bloque de código para hacer la petición.

```
Api_get(data?){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
         this.http.post(this.url + data.method, data.send).subscribe(data =>{
             resolve( data.json() );
             reject({status:false});
         })
     })

  }
```

La petición se ejecuta y trae los datos pero en un objeto __zone_symbol__value array[]
No se si estoy haciendo algo mal espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

necesitas mapear tu respuesta en un provider por ejemplo un caso muy usado para un login mira:

**PROVIDER:**

```js
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  public headers;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  login(username, password) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let body = `username=${username}&password=${password}`;
    return this._http.post('http://localhost/api/login', body, { "headers": this.headers })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch((err:any)=> {
        return Observable.of(undefined)
      });
  }
}
```

**PAGINA.ts:**

```js
import { LoginService } from '../../providers/login-service'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  providers: [ LoginService, Globals, UsersService, Keyboard]
})

@Injectable()
export class LoginPage {
  constructor(private _loginService: LoginService) {}
login(){
var username = this.user.username;
var password = this.user.password;
this._loginService.login(username, password)
  .subscribe(data => {
    if(data === undefined){
      console.log("USUARIO INVALIDO");
    } else {
      //Datos del usuario
      console.log(data); 
    }
  });
}
}
```

Pero si es necesario que lo mapees con el .map de la función del Promise, checa éste código como ejemplo y espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por el ejemplo, lo que pretendía hacer era regresar desde la función del provider el array o el abjeto JSON, investigando un poco aprendí que no puedes regresar el valor de una promesa, se debe ingresar a la promesa para obtener el valor y ahí mismo procesar la información.